# How to find every symbolic link on a server?

Tags: find, options

I need to find every symbolic link on the server.

The version is `AIX 6.1`.

`man find` says

```
-L Follow symbolic links
```

But `find -L` is not a proper usage. `Usage: find [-H | -L] Path-list [Expression-list]`

I tried to Google this but couldn't find answers.

Comment: By default, if you use `find /some/directory -name '*.txt'`, the `find` command will not follow any symbolic links it finds as it is traversing the sub-structure of the starting directory. If you add the `-L` option, it will follow symbolic links (and, in particular, if any of those links leads to a directory, it will traverse that remote directory). The reason why this is not the default behaviour is that it can lead to 'infinite' paths. Consider what happens when you have a symlink created by `ln -s . xyz`...without the `-L`, there'll be no problem; with it, `find` runs for a long time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to pass a top directory name. Some versions of `find` assume the current directory if you omit it, but not AIX's. Also, `-L` isn't what you want here: it tells `find` to follow symbolic links, but that's not what you're asking, you're asking to find symbolic links.

`find / -type l -print` will print out all the symbolic links.

See [man find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know what the symbolic link points to, enter following command:

`find / -type l -exec ls -l {} \;`